# Async data fetch and Fragment loading

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have `Activity` that fetches data in background and after it's done it should update Fragment's `Spinner`, but it always throw `NullPointerException`.

I use this to do it:

```
SearchPlaceFragment s = new SearchPlaceFragment();
s.updateSpinner(cityNames);
```

Fragment is created programatically so there is no ID or tag I can refer to. How can I do it most simple way? Is there any way to get to the existing fragments?

Comment: you can call getArguments().putAll(bundle) , and you can here send some data(as a bundle) to the existing fragment of yours. But why don't you use the async task in the fragment and update it there using onPostExecute()?

Comment: Thought it would be faster to start in Activity and then pass it, but seems to be too much hussle for it

Comment: You can use the activity to create the Fragment , then in the fragment you do what you gotta do :)

Comment: Gonna do that then. Maybe in fact I was overcomplicating it :) Cheers!